# How can I make a linear relation between two vectors?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to make a correlation plot with plot_ly

As an example I do

```
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- plot_ly(
  d, x = ~carat, y = ~price,
  # Hover text:
  text = ~paste("Price: ", price, '$<br>Cut:', cut),
  color = ~carat, size = ~carat
)
```

then plot

but how can I make the linear line and calculate the R2? 
is there a way to do it?

If you know any other way to do it, please let me know.

For example, something like this would be great

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

http://vault.hanover.edu/~altermattw/courses/220/R/corr/corr_2.html

I tried to do it with:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = Outcome)) +     
        geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

which I am getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
fit <- lm(price ~ carat-1, data = d)
summary(fit)$adj.r.squared

a <- list(
    x = 2,
    y = 5000,
    text = "R2 = 0.88",
    xref = "x",
    yref = "y",
    showarrow = FALSE,
    arrowhead = 7
)


plot_ly() %>% add_markers(data = d, x= ~ carat, y = ~ price, color = ~carat, size = ~carat, name = "Size", marker=list(colorbar=list(title='Colorbar'))) %>%  
    add_lines(x = ~carat, y = fitted(fit), name = "Regression line") %>% 
    layout(annotations = a)
```

[image]

Comment: Warning messages:
1: Numeric color variables cannot (yet) be mapped to lines.
 when the trace type is 'scatter' or 'scattergl'.
 
2: plotly.js doesn't yet support line.width arrays, track this issue for progress

Comment: i see your point. is there any possibility to discard the extrapolation? the extreme values? i will accept your answer anyway if you know or not

Comment: see edits. You can create a new data set and subset for values above 0

Comment: no no, look at your line, it goes with an intercept. i want to pass through 0 , no intercept and calculate the correlation , do you know what i mean?

Comment: I liked it and accepted it. however, there are two problems with it . add the ) after the fit. also can you tell me how to add the R2 in a specific place? also is there any possibility to change the lenegd name ?

Comment: see edits; as for the R2, please look at **a**, you can see you define the location with x and y.

Comment: do you know how to remove the size and Regression line under the legend ?

Comment: that will off all legend , I only want to not have size and Regression line

Comment: this work for me: plot_ly() %>% add_markers(data = d, x= ~ carat, y = ~ price, color = ~carat, size = ~carat, name = "Size", marker=list(colorbar=list(title='Colorbar'))) %>%  
    add_lines(x = ~carat, y = fitted(fit), name = "Regression line", showlegend=FALSE) %>% 
    layout(annotations = a)